# SVN HTML file not opening in chrome

Tags: svn

I have created SVN subversion for design prototypes and created HTML files with Design to show client.

The HTML file is in opening fine in IE.  In Firefox and Chrome it is displaying the HTML code not the page.

How do I get it correctly displayed in Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: I can't figure out how this can be related at all to Subversion... What are the file name and contents? How do you open the file?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have not set the mime type for the file, so it is being sent as text/plain by the server, and interpreted accordingly by the two browsers.

If your file is called "myfile.html", try setting its mime type, thus:

```
svn propset svn:mime-type "text/html" myfile.html
```

See the [red-bean SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.browsing.mimetype) (and [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.propset.html)) for details.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. Under what circumstances does the browser make use of Subversion's `svn:mime-type` property?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario If you set up your repository to be browsable over HTTP, the value of the svn:mime-type property of a file is used to provide the Content-Type header when serving it to a browser.  See my update for a link to the documentation

Comment: Alright, that explains the question itself. If you use a repository browser to inspect your HTML files you'll obviously see your source code by default.